# cannot access a disposed object. Object Name:'MarshalingwindowFrame'

Tags: visual-studio-2010, devexpress, report

During openning my project in Visual Studio 2010 this issue came out. 
[image]

So, how can I fix it? Can't open DataSet and contiu any other work in VS. Please, tell me what can be th ereason?

Comment: I just started getting this one today. Did you recently upgrade to 12.1? I am wondering if something screwed up?

Comment: Yes, just upgraded with project convertor. What can provide this isuue?

Answer (score 0):

For me, the error disappeared after disabling **S**ource **C**ode **C**ontrol integration. To disable SCC, do like this:

- In the IDE Go to **`Tools->Options->Source Control->Plug-in Selection`** dialog page.
- Select **`None`** from the drop-down box labeled **`Current Source Control plug-in:`**.